# How to prove that the inverse of a matrix is unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

The ring of matrix is not an integral domain. How to prove that the inverse is unique?

Comment: You don't need it to be an integral domain to have unique inverses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $ab=ba=1$, and if also $ac=ca=1$, you have $c=(ba)c=b(ac)=b$. In fact, if you reread it, this shows that whenever you know both a left inverse exists and a right inverse exists, then actually they are the same element, so it is a two-sided inverse and it is unique.

It has little to do with integral domains: it's true for any associative operation with an identity.

Comment: You could also mention that your argument actually shows that if a left inverse and a right inverse exist, then they are equal and so he inverse exists and is unique.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Good idea: I added that. Thanks!